# Visual Studio WinForm application should compile and output to specific directory

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, desktop-application

I want to compile and output exe/dlls for Visual Studio 2022/.NET 6.0 WinForm project in the following directory:

`GB3`: root dir containing exe/dlls

`--config`: calibration.txt, appsettings.json

`--logs`: log files

`--db`: sqlite db

config, logs and db are sub-folders.

I have right-clicked on `Project->Properties->Output->Base output path` to set `GB3` as Base output path.

Now the problem is that Visual Studio is automatically creating `\Debug\net6.0-windows` folder under `GB3`, and outputs exe and dlls under `GB3\Debug\net6.0-windows` instead of simply under ''GB3''. How can I output exe and dlls under ''GB3'' and not `GB3\Debug\net6.0-windows`? Many thanks in advance

Comment: Adding ``<AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>`` in project file removed ``net6.0-windows`` folder but ``Debug`` folder is still created

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You also need to use `OutputPath` instead of `BaseOutputPath`, the project file should look like the following.

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>WinExe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0-windows</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <OutputPath>GB3\</OutputPath>
    <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Adding following created the desired output structure: ``<BaseOutputPath>GB3</BaseOutputPath>
 <OutputPath>GB3</OutputPath>
 <AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>false</AppendTargetFrameworkToOutputPath>
 <AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>false</AppendRuntimeIdentifierToOutputPath>``